# Runtime has encountered a fatal error

Tags: c#, .net, combobox, fatal-error, textchanged

I am trying to call following function on text change event of combo box:

```
private void comboBoxManfacturer_TextChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     comboBoxManfacturer.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
     comboBoxManfacturer.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems;
}
```

With text change events everything works perfect, but with greater number of calls of text change it give exception

> The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error
>   was at 0xf2aee661, on thread 0x10e8. The error code is 0xc0000005.
>   This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable
>   portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user
>   marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the
>   stack.

As i am new with exception i don't know how to handle this, why it occurred and most important how to solve this.

Comment: Getting code like this to crash with that exception takes considerable effort.  You cannot get help without a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).  Do count on this being environmental, try it on another machine.  And be wary of any unmanaged code that runs in your process, the usual source of this kind of failure.

Comment: Do you use `Thread`, `Task` or `BackgroundWorker`?

Comment: It's most likely not a CLR bug, but probably a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unusual_software_bug#Heisenbug). We can't really say what's causing it, though, without seeing your code. Try turning on [Managed Debugging Assistants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d21c150d.aspx) to figure out if some error or access violation is being suppressed.

Comment: @Sinatr no i work on main thread.

Comment: If it is well reproducible, then try to make a small project so others can try it. More likely reason and solution are trivial: do windows update, re-install framework, etc.

Comment: How do you know the error occurred in this portion of your code? I remember we got this error when we used some third-party COM component, but never managed to solve it.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Reasons- 1) Program execution breaks in this part only. 2) No other method is called on text change event. 3) And Last without this method everything works fine.

Comment: Surprisingly it is happening for ONLY one of the projects in my solution. I've got a dozen of projects in my solution but all others run without any issue. The one in which I'm facing this issue is a C# console application. To add to info, I had taken a huge bulk of pending windows 7 update in the morning yesterday but if that would have been the root cause then it should have affected the startup pattern of all the projects in the solution. I'm using Visual Studio 2010. The issue happens only during debugging the project from VS. Its output exe from debug folder works perfect.

Comment: can you try this : Go to project properties of your project -> Go to "Debug" tab -> Go to "Enable Debuggers" section in right pane -> Check the "Enable unmanaged code debugging" check box. Save project properties and try running your application again.